# php guzzle request file upload and send body

Tags: php, file, post, request, guzzle

**I want to send file and body HTTP request with guzzle but API not responding gets bad request error**

ı had an error from response 
have two ,
response for status 400
response getReasonPhrase()  ı get bad request

```
<?php


require_once "vendor/autoload.php";


use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;



$file="yeni.zip";
$hash=md5_file($file);

$binary=file_get_contents($file);



$soapbody='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:get="http://fitcons.com/earchive/invoice">
         <soapenv:Header/>
         <soapenv:Body>
         <get:sendInvoiceRequestType>
         <senderID>6310700163</senderID>
         <receiverID>53077224954</receiverID>
         <docType>XML</docType>
         <fileName>newarsiv.xml</fileName>
         <hash>'.$hash.'</hash>
         <binaryData>'.$binary.'</binaryData>
         </get:sendInvoiceRequestType>
         </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';



$client=new Client();




$url="https://earsivwstest.fitbulut.com/ClientEArsivServicesPort.svc";


$options=[
    'auth' => ['blabla', 'blabla'],
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml','cache-control'=>'no-control'],
    'SOAPAction'=>'sendInvoice',
    'body' => $soapbody,
    'http_errors'=>false,
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'  =>"yeni.zip",
            'Filename'  => "yeni.zip",
            'contents'      => fopen($file, 'r'),
            'headers'       =>  [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'form-data; name="yeni.zip"; filename="yeni.zip"'
                ]


            ]

]


];


$response = $client->request('POST', $url,$options);


echo $response->getReasonPhrase()."\n".$response->getStatusCode();



var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

result

> ,Internal Server Error 500string(698) "a:ActionNotSupportedThe message with Action '' cannot be processed at the
>   receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
>   This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions
>   between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between
>   the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the
>   same contract and the same binding (including security requirements,
>   e.g. Message, Transport,
>   None)."
>   NKolayOfiss-MacBook-Pro:soapguzzle nkolayofis$ php index.php  ,Bad
>   Request 400string(0) ""

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `body` and `multipart` in the same time. `multipart` internally forms the body, and `body` is the option to set the body of your HTTP request directly. It just doesn't make any sense to mix them together.

In your example you should read the API's documentation.

Comment: thanks ,sent as binary, problem solved ago two  week